# Como ajustar a reta de regressão de modo que 90% dos fiquem abaixo da reta?

Tags: r, regressão

tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados no R:

```
x <- c(0.1, 3, 4, 5, 9, 12, 13, 19, 22, 25)
y <- c(5, 12, 17, 23, 28, 39, 26, 31, 38, 40)
bd <- data.frame(x, y)
```

Minha pergunta é como eu faço no R para gerar um modelo de regressão que melhor se ajuste de forma que 90% dos dados fiquem abaixo da linha de regressão e que o modelo estime a origem (zero).

Parece que o modelo geométrico se ajusta melhor a este caso. Tentei utilizar a exponencial conforme a seguir, ele começa na origem mais os dados não ficam 90% abaixo da curva.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(bd,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', 
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 1, b = 1)), 
              se = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá! O que você já tentou fazer para tentar solucionar este problema? Edite sua pergunta e compartilhe conosco seu código, suas tentativas, que erros/problemas ocorreram, etc.

Comment: As setas de atribuição estão ao contrário.

Comment: Está à procura de `fit0 <- quantreg::rq(y ~ 0 + x, tau = 0.90)`?

Comment: Obrigado Rui, tentei fazer conforme colocou, mas acho que a reta não se ajusta bem aos dados, tentei utilizar a exponencial conforme a seguir, ele começa na origem mais os dados não ficam 90% abaixo da curva:  ggplot(bd,aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = 'y~a*x^b', start = list(a = 1,b=1),tau =0.9, se=FALSE)

Comment: `ggplot(bd, aes(x = log(x), y = log(y))) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = 'quantreg::rq', formula = 'y ~ x', method.args = list(tau = 0.9), se = FALSE)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas a pergunta foi aberta, pode ser dada resposta no campo correspondente agora.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui estão duas maneiras de resolver o problema utilizando o pacote `quantreg`.

A fórmula `y = a*x^b` pode ser transformada aplicando logaritmos e ajustar o modelo resultante, ou seja, uma reta de regressão robusta ao quantil `0.90`.

**1.** Isso pode ser feito automaticamente com a função `stat_smooth` do pacote `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(bd, aes(x = log(x), y = log(y))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = quantreg::rq, formula = 'y ~ x', 
              method.args = list(tau = 0.9), se = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2.** Também se podem fazer um ajuste e calcular os valores ajustados.

```
fit90 <- quantreg::rq(log(y) ~ log(x), tau = 0.90, data = bd)
xnew <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 50)
y90 <- exp(predict(fit90, newdata = data.frame(x = xnew)))
pred90 <- data.frame(x = xnew, y = y90)

ggplot(bd, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = pred90, aes(x, y), colour = "blue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]